# Basis of a tangent space: arbitrary or fixed?

Tags: differential-geometry

This might be a very basic question but oftentimes in textbooks or papers I encounter the phrase "for a choice of orthonormal basis in the tangent space", which implies an arbitrary choice of basis in tangent spaces, however I thought that tangent spaces had a canonical basis given by the differential operators $\partial/\partial x_i$. What am I missing here?

Comment: To define $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ you need to make a choice of local coordinates $x_i$.

Comment: So, when encountered, this phrase implies that one can choose the local coordinate charts such that they form an orthonormal basis?

Comment: The phrase doesn't make any claims about local coordinates at all; picking an orthonormal basis in the tangent space is just picking an orthonormal basis in the tangent space.

Comment: Also, the tangent vectors $\partial/\partial x^i$ may not be orthonormal. In fact, they usually cannot be. Moreover, it makes sense only if you are given a riemannian metric.

Comment: @DIdier_ 's comment is exactly my point. There is no way (that I see) to "control" the orthonormality of the tangent vectors. Furthermore, if they form a basis (subject to local parameterization) in a tangent space, how is there meaning to making arbitrary choices independent of local coordinates?

Comment: Because the tangent space is a vector space that is defined without coordinates. Given a riemannian metric $g$, $g_p$ is an innter product on $T_pM$ and there is a notion of orthogonality for vectors in $T_pM$. As $p\mapsto g_p$ is smooth, one can locally defined smooth orthonormal sections. They usually does not exist globally.

Comment: Ah I think I'm beginning to understand. Given a metric tensor (which is also parameterization invariant) one can use it to construct an orthonormal basis out of the tangent vectors (?)